# Return subset of DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

# create simple dataset of people
data = {'Name': ["John", "Anna", "Peter", "Linda"],
        'Location': ["New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "London"],
        'Age': [24, 13, 53, 33]
       }
data_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)
# IPython.display allows "pretty printing" of dataframes
# in the Jupyter notebook
#display(data_pandas)
data_pandas
```

What is returned is the following DF:

```
    Age  Location   Name
0   24   New York   John
1   13   Paris      Anna
2   53   Berlin     Peter
3   33   London     Linda
```

I then do this:

```
olderThan30 = data_pandas[data_pandas > 30]
olderThan30
```

And it returns the following:

```
    Age     Location    Name
0   NaN     New York    John
1   NaN     Paris       Anna
2   53.0    Berlin      Peter
3   33.0    London      Linda
```

---

What I would like to **return is only those that have the Age column greater than 30.** Something like this:

```
    Age     Location    Name
2   53.0    Berlin      Peter
3   33.0    London      Linda
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the appropriate [boolean condition](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to mask:

```
In [104]:
data_pandas[data_pandas['Age'] > 30]

Out[104]:
   Age Location   Name
2   53   Berlin  Peter
3   33   London  Linda
```

what you did was compare the entire df:

```
In [105]:
data_pandas > 30

Out[105]:
     Age Location  Name
0  False     True  True
1  False     True  True
2   True     True  True
3   True     True  True
```

this then masks the cells in the entire df, which is why you get `NaN` in the first 2 rows of age

Whilst masking just the col of interest:

```
In [106]:
data_pandas['Age'] > 30

Out[106]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Age, dtype: bool
```

when passed as a mask to a df, masks the rows

as @JonClements has suggested, you may feel more comfortable using [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [110]:
data_pandas.query('Age > 30')

Out[110]:
   Age Location   Name
2   53   Berlin  Peter
3   33   London  Linda
```

This has a dependency on `numexpr` library but this is normally installed correctly in my experience

Comment: Might be worth noting that if numexpr is available using df.query is an option.

Comment: @JonClements sure will update, I don't use `query` so much